# CAShapeLayer not tapable when above UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIScrollView` that has a circular shape and inside it there is a image placed on the screen and above the UIScrollView shape to the right side of it.

I also have a `CAShapeLayer` that has a circular shape too that is overlapping a little, becouse i want it to look like that.

The problem is my `touchesBegan` cant detect tap in the overlapping area of the `CAShapeLayer`.

I want to be able to scroll the image inside UIScrollView while be able to tap the whole area of the CAShapeLayer object with objective c.

Please help me and show me how... i don't know how to do it.. have searched in 4 days.. but i can't find a way.

Comment: please share the code that you have tried so far

Comment: Hi Adam. I really want to do that, but in my frustration time i have deleted the code, becouse i felt it was useless...